# visual studio code says I have a problem so I want to fix it

Tags: css

```
.slogan .company-title {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(120deg, var(--primary-color-alt), var(--primary-color));
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

I want to solve this problem and visual says:

> Also define the standard property 'background-clip' for
> compatibilitycss(vendorPrefix)

Comment: What part of the error message are you having trouble understanding? It's fairly self-explanatory...

Comment: Just add a `background-clip: text;` value alongside the `-webkit-` prefixed one.

Comment: @Dai my problem at this line -webkit-background-clip: text;